# JS очень медленно работает

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Делаю игру на JS, очень сильно виснет.

Проведя профилирование в Opera GX выяснил, что ws.onmessage замедляет работу:
[image: профилирование]
Код на 835 строчке:

```
ws.onmessage = message => {
  const response = JSON.parse(message.data);
  if (response.method === "connect"){
    clientID = response.clientID;
    loginWind.style.display = 'none';
    logo.style.display = 'none';
    version.style.display = 'none';
    canvas.style.display = '';
    news.style.display = 'none';
    messageBox.style.display = 'none';
    messageBox.innerHTML = "";
    sendNick = {
      "method": "nick",
      "clientID": clientID,
      "nick": name
    }
    sendWS(JSON.stringify(sendNick), ws)
  }
  if (response.method === "gameData"){
    render(response);
  }
  if (response.method === "disconnect"){
    Reason = response.reason;
    ws.close();
  }
}
```

Строка

> if (response.method === "gameData"){

отвечает за отображение игры. Что здесь не так?

P.S. Немного изменил систему отрисовки. Раньше было 2 холста, один невидимый, а другой основной. На невидимом рисовалась игра, а потом на видимый переносилась картинка. Сейчас один холст, профилирование такое:
[image: профилирование 2]

Comment: За что функция отвечает и когда вызвается? Ждет ли функция полученя данных от сервера?

Comment: @Greg-- функция отвечает за отрисовку игры, вызывается когда получит данные от сервера. И дело вовсе не в сервере, ведь когда игрок заходит на сервер (Нажимает кнопку играть) сервер моментально пишет что игрок нажал кнопку.

Comment: Подозреваю, что проблема в функции `render`

Comment: @lksmnd с кнопкой ничего не понятно, мне кажется ответ на кнопку не показатель загрузились ли данные или нет. Вы рендерите в canvas? что именно медленно работает? какая загрузка ЦПУ и ГПУ у этой вкладки (не у браузера)?

Comment: Немного изменил систему отрисовки. Раньше было 2 холста, один невидимый, а другой основной. На невидимом рисовалась игра, а потом на видимый переносилась картинка. Сейчас один холст, профилирование добавил.

Comment: @Greg-- как можно узнать загрузку ЦПУ и ГПУ у вкладки ?

Comment: в хроме есть свой диспетчер задач: SHIFT + ESC

Comment: @Greg-- Объём потребляемой памяти: 47 024K, Процессор ~20

Comment: 20 процентов ЦПУ а что тогда медленно работает? Это при нагрузке (рендере?)  А GPU ? Медленно это сайт виснит, вкладка падает? Поставьте на ключевых отрисовках вывод в консоль с меткой времени и увидите на каком этапе прорисовки игры у вас тормоза)

Comment: @Greg-- медленно работает передвижение. Игра по типу агарио. Хотя если посмотреть на сервере какие у меня координаты то там все нормально.

Comment: @Greg-- Повороты медленно работают, то есть повернул наверх и через секунд 7 только повернулся. Ну или когда экран с выбором имени, написал имя, нажал кнопку старт и через такие же 7 секунд только запускается.

Comment: Проблема в перерендеривании кадров видимо, вы используюте [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)? попробуйте сделать демку с простым движением в виде сниппета, тогда понятно будет. Каждий поворот лагает или только один раз?